# WebForms: How detect if I pushed ENTER Key or I clicked to a button to look for data

Tags: c#, webforms

I have the typical Web Form with textbox, combobox and a buttonbox (which is the search button).

After push in button I have to fill the data in a table.

All of that controls are inside a FORM.

how can i detect if after push ENTER Key I want to simulate the search button?

Comment: Look at setting default button attribute on form tag - very descriptive article here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35180/How-To-set-Default-Button-for-ENTER-key-pressed-ev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(tb_KeyDown);

    private void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //enter key is down
        } 
    }
```